# MySQL UPDATE query executes but table is not updated

Tags: php, mysql

```
if(isset($_POST['select4']))
{$roomdes=$_POST['select4'];}
if(isset($_POST['select5']))
{$roomid=$_POST['select5'];}
$roomid=mysql_real_escape_string('$roomid');
$roomdes=mysql_real_escape_string('$roomdes');

if(isset($_POST['button2']))

{
$sql2="UPDATE master_table SET Room_booked=1 WHERE Room_type='$roomdes' AND Room_id='$roomid'";
$res3=mysql_query($sql2);
echo"done";
echo $sql2;
if(!$res3)
{echo"not being updated";}
else echo" \nupdatedddd\n";

}
```

Here updated gets printed but my table dosen't get updated. What should I do?

Comment: Try $res3=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Injection Prone Coding

Comment: Well, `mysql_query` returns `false` only on errors, so your `update` could be valid and return `true`, but not actually update the table.

Comment: -1 because, well, I don't like "plzzzzz" or "????????", along with lack of every possible useful information to explain the problem. You talk to people in real life like that too?

Comment: echo this line `echo $sql2="UPDATE master_table SET Room_booked=1 WHERE Room_type='$roomdes' AND Room_id='$roomid'";` and directly run into your database and see what does it says

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com//q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated. Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Do you expect a beginner (which this person obviously is) to even know what that means? Probably a good idea to expound on that to help them out.

Answer (score 2):

```
$roomid=mysql_real_escape_string('$roomid');
$roomdes=mysql_real_escape_string('$roomdes');
```

Should be:

```
$roomid=mysql_real_escape_string($roomid);
$roomdes=mysql_real_escape_string($roomdes);
```

As when they're wrapped in apostrophes (i.e. `'`) PHP assumes that's the string not the variable.

You can also try the following to see if there was an error updating it:

```
 $res3 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it says Notice: Undefined variable: roomid  on line 68
Undefined variable: roomdes in D:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 69